# Why does this python generator act like this?

Tags: python, generator

```
def upto(n):
    items = []
    for i in range(n):
        items.append(i)
        yield items

print(list(upto(2)))
```

Why is the print output `[[0,1],[0,1]]`? When I call next on upto(2) twice, it `yields [0]` the first time and `[0,1]` the second time, so shouldn't the result be `[[0], [0,1]]`?

Comment: you need to yield outside the for loop

Comment: This is related to shallow and deep copies. Run this sequence of code and see if that helps you learn what a shallow copy is. `a=upto(2)
b=next(a)
print(b)
next(a)
print(b)`

Comment: You are yielding *exactly the same list object* each time.  Yes, it's changing length each time, but you aren't doing anything that would capture or display the state of the list at that moment in time.  Instead, you're just accumulating references to this one list.  When you finally display them, all the references necessarily display the same thing, which is the final state of the list.

Comment: @user1558604 there is no shallow copy here. There is no copying *at all*, that's the issue. Indeed, a shallow copy would have worked

Answer (score 2):

you need to yield a copy try `yield items[:]`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]:

def upto(n):
    items = []
    for i in range(n):
        items.append(i)
        yield items.copy()

list(upto(2))

Out[1]: [[0], [0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is,you are referencing the same list(list work by reference) when trying to call list method on a generator. the list you are yielding is updated each time you loop through.so when you list up the generator it gets the updated one. for getting what you want you could do one of the following two things,

1. yield a new list every time you loop through, like `yield items[:]`
2. iterate through the returned generator, like 
   `for i in upto(2):`
       `print(i) # here,each time it gets the current one`